# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `table_companies`)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cloudways

I have my .env file configured with the remote DB credentials and its working on my local computer.

When I deploy the app to our dev server in the same page returns

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `table_companies`)

Is there a command that I'm missing? Why if my .env us using our cloudways database credentials is saying homestead'@'localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The production server has its own DB credentials that you should put in server's own [`.env`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#environment-configuration) file.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. How can I update the .env file in the server? Via FTP?

Comment: How did you get the rest of the files on the server? You should be able to use this method to edit the files also.

Comment: @kangular if you don't use a tool like Laravel Forge, then you can edit that file via SFTP or SSH.

Comment: We used Cloudways and the is a feature to deploy via GIT. Tried to ad .env or modify/rename .env.example via SFTP but it fails. What permissions are recommended for this file?

Comment: What error does it show? Try to edit the file with `sudo`.

Comment: It was something to do with Cloudways, I contacted their customer support and they helped me reset permission to the directory to allow me to create the .env file. Thank you for help.